# Specify breaks in scale_y_discrete in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(Day=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), clones=c("c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3"), 
                 resistance=c(0,1,1,0,1,1), virus=c("v0","v20","v30","v0","v20","v30"))

  Day clones resistance virus
1   0     c1          0    v0
2   0     c2          1   v20
3   0     c3          1   v30
4   1     c1          0    v0
5   1     c2          1   v20
6   1     c3          1   v30
```

I plot my data.frame like this, but I find it hard to specify the breaks in scale_y_discrete inside the dplyr pipeline.

```
df %>% 
  unite("new",Day:clones, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(virus,new)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = resistance), color = "black")
```

[image]

I want to be able to show only the first label of each group_by(Day).
I want to see only the **0_c1** and **1_c1** in the y-axis

Thank you for your time. Any help and comment are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a label column which is empty except for the first value in each day.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  unite(new,Day:clones, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(Day) %>%
  mutate(labels = replace(new, -1, '')) %>%
  ungroup() -> df1

ggplot(df1, aes(virus,new)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = resistance), color = "black") + 
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = df1$labels)
```

[image]